# Android Notification triggering on application startup

Tags: java, android, notifications, mobile-application

I'm trying to get my **Daily** Notification Service working properly but I am stuck with an issue.

I should receive a notification only at a specific time of the day **in the future** but I noticed that

```
if (time_that_i_set_for_notification < current_time_of_the_day) notification triggers at the boot of my app
```

That's wrong because in that condition, the notification should trigger **only the next day**, not in the instant I launch the app.

Here's my attempt to get the things working:

**I call this in my MainActivity, onCreate() method**:

```
private void scheduleNotification(int hour, int minute){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId", notifId);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notifId, notificationIntent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately at a time
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(this);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

I thought that adding `if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` I would've achieved the result I needed.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `setInexactRepeating`, add this check:

```
if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there's a wrong check there, if you change it, you should be able to solve your issue.

Here we go:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId", notifId);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notifId, notificationIntent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately at a time
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(this);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        //if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
        if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

I commented `//if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`
 because it should be unnecessary.

Let me know if it worked.

**UPDATE**: You should totally check whether the Service that handles your daily notification is high consume or not. A High-draining battery app would bother your users.